# Downgrade from Laravel 5.2 back to 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, symfony, omnipay

Downgrade from Laravel 5.2 back to 5.1, I'm using [Omnipay](https://github.com/Klinche/omnipay-cybersource-soap)

but it is not compatible with Laravel 5.2 / Symfony 3.

Or configured symfony/http-foundation:2.8.* , I have understood that it is compatible.

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.6",
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "^2.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "zgabievi/promocodes": "^0.1.5",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "dev-master",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "omnipay/omnipay": "~2.0",
        "dabsquared/omnipay-cybersource-soap": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that package that would conflict with specific Laravel versions. `omnipay/common` requires Symfony's HTTP foundation versions 2.1+ or 3.0+, which Laravel should be fine with. Give us your actual `composer.json` and the specific messages you get... and fix your question, as you've told us in the title you're doing 5.1-->5.0 but in the question you say 5.2-->5.1.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks I was reviewing composer.json and I run to do composer update.

Comment: Having hit a number of issues with 5.2 I'm staying with 5.1 anyway.  5.1 has the advantage of long term support.  I haven't seen any success stories of getting omnipay working with Laravel 5.2, in theory it should be possible but I haven't ever seen it done.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 uses Symfony 3 components, as noted in the readme you'll have to force the requirement of symfony/event-dispatcher:^2.8

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay/blob/master/README.md